# How would I test if my custom dimension exists?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm making a datapack that relies on a custom dimension. If the dimension hasn't loaded in, it will break things. When you add the datapack to a pre-existing world, then the dimension won't load until you relog (singleplayer) or restart the server (multiplayer). I'm trying to setup a function that repeats every tick (I know how to do that already) that will check if the dimension has loaded, and if it hasn't, send a message to restart the server/world. I'm trying to do this with `/execute if`, but that doesn't have a way to check dimensions (same with `/execute unless`). Another idea would be `/execute in`, but that can't return true or false.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! As you updated the question as solved, please submit an answer with your solution.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to indicate that it is solved. Instead, post your solution as an answer so that others may vote on it.